ImportError: cannot import name '_endpoint_from_view_func' from 'flask.helpers'
My App was working fine on Win11, but when pulling down to my mac and attempting to run, i see the above error.
my library versions are:
Flask                     3.0.3
Flask-Cors                4.0.0
Flask-RESTful             0.3.9
flask-restplus            0.13.0
flask-restx               1.3.0
Werkzeug                  3.0.2

and i can find no answer to this problem that relates to these versions

always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

First of all, in python usually functions named with a single leading underscore are internal functions according to PEP8, not meant to be used outside of the library.
Second _endpoint_from_view_func() appears to be in helpers.py in Flask 1.1.x, it was moved to another file in this commit. In version 3.0.x the function exists within sansion/scaffold.py
You'll have to either:

Avoid using an internal function so you can run Flask 3.0.x
Update your code so it points to the correct file that contains the function (flask/sansion/scaffold)
Downgrade to Flask 1.1.x (not recommended)


I updated the "api.py" file in the "flask_restx" directory so that the code now points to "scaffold.py" in the "flask/sansio" directory and it solved the problem. Note that (at least in my build) the directory name is "sansio" and not "sansion".
